# ffmpeg - 2nd audio stream added to video won't play

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a video that already contains an audio stream. I'm trying to add a second audio stream to that same video.

`ffmpeg -i input1.mkv -i input2.mp3 -map 0 -map 1:a -c:v copy output.mp4`

This seems very straightforward. But when I try to play the video, I can only hear one of the audio streams. This happens even if I reverse the order of the inputs, and regardless of whether I output to an mp4 or mkv file. It also happens if I map all of the streams from all of the input using `-map 0` and `-map 1`, and it still persists if I use a `wav` file for the second input instead of an `mp3`

When I use `ffprobe` to examine the output video, it's clear that there are three streams:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Duration: 00:05:05.09, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9973 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 3840x2160 [SAR 3:4 DAR 4:3], 11272 kb/s, 27.28 fps, 24 tbr, 16k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 131 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:2[0x3](und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 191 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

How do I get this video to play both of the audio streams? This seems so simple, and it's driving me crazy that I can't figure it out.

Comment: Just to be clear, a player won't play both streams together, only allow you to switch between them. You have to mix them using a filter like amix to combine them.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that only one audio stream can be played at a time. Your comment helped me solve this problem, if you make this an answer I will upvote it.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-amix